# Give an example of a function from $\mathbf N$ to $\mathbf N$ that is both onto and one-to-one (but different form the identity function)

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I was thinking something like $f(n) = \lceil\frac n 2\rceil$, would this work?

Comment: Flip $1$ and $2$, and fix everything else.

Comment: That would not be both onto *and* one-to-one.  Note: $f(1)=f(2)=1$.  You can be creative here... in fact, I encourage you to be creative.  For some inspiration, the functions that are both onto and one-to-one for finite sets are called permutations, the six permutations for $\{1,2,3\}$ to itself can be shorthanded as 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321.  The first, 123, corresponds to the identity permutation, similar to the identity function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Doesn't $f(1)=f(2)$ for your example?

Comment: I will point out, there are *infinitely many* correct answers.  Some of them are quite fun and exciting, while others are rather bland.  A question like this however is a chance to be creative and think outside the box.  Here is the start to a slightly more interesting answer: $\color{red}{5},1,\color{red}{10},2,\color{red}{15},3,\color{red}{20},4,\color{red}{25},6,\color{red}{30},7,\dots$

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm unable to work out the algorithm, but in your example 0 is left unmapped.

Comment: Presumably @JMoravitz was thinking of the version of $\mathbb N$ that doesn't include $0$, but this is easily fixed.

Comment: @Elliott Some authors include zero as an element of $\Bbb N$ while others do not.  If you want to include $0$ then put it at the start.  As for writing out the function I describe explicitly, it is easy to write with words but harder to write with symbols.  With words, in each odd position you write the smallest multiple of five not yet written.  In each even position you write the smallest non-multiple of five not yet written.  You can write a formula for it (*it is easiest but not necessary to use cases*) and it can be a fun challenge if you haven't written similar functions before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example

$$f(n)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
2\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ n=1\\
1\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ n=2\\
n\ \text{ otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Answer (score 1):

Define $f(n)=\begin{cases}  n-1, n\, \text{even}\\  n+1, n \,\text{odd}\end{cases}$